# Execute a command until another command has finished

Tags: c#, reactiveui

I have something like this:

```
this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.SearchText)
    .Where(text => !string.IsNullOrempty(text))
    .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.25))
    .InvokeCommand(searchCmd);
```

Where SearchText is an string property bindied to a textbox and searchCmd is a ReactiveCommand.

What I want is, if searchCmd is already running, the observable should wait. For example, if the user typed "gener" and after an small pause he types "ally", the command will be still running, and will not execute for "generally", only "gener".

Any idea?

EDIT: What I'm doing (and it looks that it works):

First I Added an OAPH:

```
readonly ObservableAsPropertyHelper<bool> isCmdRunning;
```

And a property:

```
public bool IsCmdRunning => isCmdRunning.Value;
```

Then, in the cosntructor:

```
this.searchCmd.IsExecuting
    .ToProperty(this, x => x.IsCmdRunning, out isCmdRunning);
```

And finally:

```
this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.SearchText, x => x.IsCmdRunning, (search, running) => new {Search = search, Running = running})
    .Where(value => !string.IsNullOrempty(value.Search) && !value.Running)
    .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.25))
    .Select(value => value.Search)
    .InvokeCommand(searchCmd);
```

But I don't know if there is a better way.

Comment: Have you seen this video already? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DYEbUF4xs1Q I believe there is an example in there that should suit your needs.

Comment: does adding a .Where( t => ! searchCmd.IsBusy ) work?

Comment: @LeonPierre I think that the example is not for ReactiveUI commands.

Comment: @kenny I took your idea, check the edit.

Comment: @Luis when you create a reactive command there is a property called IsExecuting. I believe that is what your looking for.

Comment: @Luis great and you fixed my bad memory ;) ! IsExecuting

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a good solution using CancellationToken.

The Search command:

```
Search = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromObservable(
    () => Observable
        .StartAsync(ct => SearchImpl(ct))
        .TakeUntil(CancelSearch));
```

The CancelSearch command:

```
CancelSearch = Command.Create(() => {}, Search.IsExecuting);
```

And finally:

```
this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.SearchText)
    .Do(_ => Observable.Return(Unit.Default).InvokeCommand(CancelSearch))
    .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.25))
    .InvokeCommand(searchCmd);
```